# Use of DISTINCT with T-SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm running the following stored procedure and there's a join of Classes and Dates tables. However, out of seven test records, I'm getting a single duplicate record in the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Classes.Title, dbo.Classes.ClassTime, dbo.Classes.Category, 
    dbo.Classes.SubCategory1, dbo.Classes.[Description],dbo.Classes.ContactName, 
    dbo.Classes.ContactPhone, dbo.Classes.Location, dbo.Classes.Room,
    dbo.Dates.StartDate
    FROM dbo.Classes INNER JOIN dbo.Dates ON dbo.Classes.ClassID = dbo.Dates.ClassID
    ORDER BY StartDate DESC
```

Comment: Most likely the StartDates (or ClassTime) of those two rows differ somehow but the difference doesn't show up in the output. You can verify this by dropping the StartDate column from your results.

Comment: Lieven, not enough coffee! You were right so please create your response as an answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: Been there <g>. I'll post an answer, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely one of your `Date` columns of those two rows differ somewhat but the difference doesn't show up in the output.

You can verify this by dropping those columns from your results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Classes.Title
       , dbo.Classes.Category
       , dbo.Classes.SubCategory1
       , dbo.Classes.[Description]
       , dbo.Classes.ContactName
       , dbo.Classes.ContactPhone
       , dbo.Classes.Location
       , dbo.Classes.Room
FROM   dbo.Classes 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Dates ON dbo.Classes.ClassID = dbo.Dates.ClassID
```

On a different note, I would advice you to use aliases to improve the readability of the statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Classes.Title
       , c.Category
       , c.SubCategory1
       , c.[Description]
       , c.ContactName
       , c.ContactPhone
       , c.Location
       , c.Room
FROM   dbo.Classes AS c
       INNER JOIN dbo.Dates AS d ON c.ClassID = d.ClassID
```